# Sending data to a device using the BluetoothGattCallback/BLE device

Tags: java, android-studio

I am working on an app in Android Studio that receives data from a device and displays it in the app. The app is able to read data, using a `.read()` method, but the app isn't able to send data to the device using the `.write()` method. I believe I'm passing all the correct parameters, but I can't figure out what's wrong with the `.write()` method. (Attached pictures of the `.read()` and `.write()` methods).

[image: read method]
[image: write method]